# Efficient way to filter a number of things

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

There is a list of venues. Each venue has a price attached to it which is given, and a latlon. The user enters a max distance and a max price, and the app returns a list of venues that fit those criteria. The distance needs to be calculated on the query, but I can make some sort of structure using the price or the given latlons. I already know how to figure this out in O(n) - I traverse a list of restauraunts, adding them to a result if they fit the criteria.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? I'm thinking making a BST using the price as a key (which can be calculated before runtime), then cutting off a section of the BST that's over the price limit, and then iterating through everything in the BST, but this is still in O(n), right?

Comment: If everything fits your criteria, then everything has to be returned, so you can't to better than Omega(n) in the worst case. Typical cases may be different.

Comment: I'm thinking I could start with a structure with everything in it, modify it, then return it? That way I don't actually need to iterate over everything, right?

Comment: Well if you have preprocessing, then a single query may be less than that, yeah. No idea how you could go about it, though.

Comment: Is this desktop or smart phone app? Is all possible data already in app's working memory? What technologies do you use (language, databases, web services)? What is the expected value of `n`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this problem is to treat it as a multidimensional range search problem. Each venue can be thought of as a point in a three-dimensional space given by its longitude, latitude, and price. If you want to find all venues within a certain radius of a given point whose price is at most some amount, then you're searching for all points in a cylinder with the given center and radius whose upper and lower bounds are the max price and 0, respectively.

You might want to consider using a multidimesional search tree structure like a k-d tree or R-tree to solve this problem. Once you have this structure, search the structure for the bounding box of the cylinder to get back a list of candidate points. Then, test each point in that box to see if it's inside the cylinder. Assuming the points are somewhat evenly distributed, you'll find that roughly a π / 4 fraction of them are in the cylinder, so you won't waste too much effort.